# x86_64 errors with MFP Cordova project

Tags: xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, mobilefirst-cli

I've built a MFP Cordova project with the MFP CLI 7.1

when I open xcode and try to run the project I get arch errors related to the StoragePlugin.o

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_JSON_STORE_DATABASE_NOT_OPEN", referenced from:
  ___23-[StoragePlugin store:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
  ___30-[StoragePlugin advancedFind:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
  ___22-[StoragePlugin find:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
  ___26-[StoragePlugin findById:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
  ___25-[StoragePlugin replace:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
  ___24-[StoragePlugin remove:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
  ___28-[StoragePlugin localCount:]_block_invoke_2 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(StoragePlugin.o)
```

I get 52 errors in all

Whats up?

Comment: What do you know of the symbol `JSON_STORE_DATABASE_NOT_OPEN`?  I get no hits on the internet, so I'm inclined to believe it's part of your project.

Comment: yes its part of the IBM mobilefirst platform

Comment: waiting for IBM to chime in

Comment: As usual, you need to mention the build you're using. ...

Comment: 7.1.0.00.20151012-1548

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent regression introduced in the Cordova application type regarding JSONStore. It was resolved on October 20th, while you are using a build from October 15th.

Download the *latest* CLI build available from IBM Fix Central ([or this one](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_7.1.0.zip) from November *14th*). It will contain the following APAR fix: PI50663 PURE CORDOVA APP BUILD ERROR DUE TO JSONSTORE CHANGES

Create a new app using the newer build and you should be good to go.

Comment: is this link you gave the latest mfp cli, how do I get to IBM fix central to make sure?

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you should know how to login. Otherwise use the build from the link.